# Is the use of many custom field not good for server?

Tags: custom-field

Using many custom fields
is really bad for the server, so you should avoid it as much as possible.
It was written in this forum.

I'm wondering whether to receive the information entered by the user in [post-content] or　[custom field].

The information that receive is not very long and is formally a string that can be received by both parties. Which should I do?

Comment: It depends entirely what you're using it for. There's not enough information in your question. What are you trying to do?

Comment: What are they posting? Why would you consider post meta?

Comment: It depends on what you do with it, but I don't see any reason you shouldn't just use post content.

Comment: "using many custom fields is really bad for the server" is very vague. Just placing data in meta isn't going to be "bad for the server". Your queries might be slower, depending on what you are doing with that data. But then again throwing it all into post content is not granular and will severely restrict what you can query also. It all depends what you are doing with the data once it is in your DB.